# codeigniter check for user session in every controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods, controller

I have this private session in one of my controllers that checks if a user is logged in:

```
function _is_logged_in() {

   $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');

   if (!isset($user)) { 
      return false; 
   } 
   else { 
      return true;
   }

}
```

Problem is that I have more than one Controller. How can I use this function in those other controllers? Redefining the function in every Controller isn't very 'DRY'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Another option is to create a base controller.  Place the function in the base controller and then inherit from this.

To achieve this in CodeIgniter, create a file called MY_Controller.php in the libraries folder of your application.

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        return isset($user);
    }
}
```

Then make your controller inherit from this base controller.

```
class X extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function do_something()
    {
        if ($this->is_logged_in())
        {
            // User is logged in.  Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, I really like the idea. I think it's a bit more practical than using a helper.

Comment: My controller doesn't get detected, i get this error: Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\mobilehome\application\controllers\links.php on line 3 ............ any idea how I can autoload it somewhere? Or should I just include it on top of every controller?

Comment: I think the controllers need constructors.  `function __construct(){parent::__construct();}`

Comment: Sorry Sied. Rocket is right. I had forgotten the constructors. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for a great down to earth answer which explained things well.

Answer (score 40):

Put it in a helper and autoload it.

helpers/login_helper.php:

```
function is_logged_in() {
    // Get current CodeIgniter instance
    $CI =& get_instance();
    // We need to use $CI->session instead of $this->session
    $user = $CI->session->userdata('user_data');
    if (!isset($user)) { return false; } else { return true; }
}
```

config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('login');
```

Then in your controller you can call:

```
is_logged_in();
```

Comment: how do I call the session class from outside a class? I'm getting this error with your code: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampplite\htdocs\mobilehome\application\helpers\login_helper.php on line 4 ... thanks!

Comment: You don't use `$this` in a helper.  Please look again at the code in the answer.  In helpers (and libraries), to use CodeIgniter functions, you need to get the CodeIgniter instance.  `$CI =& get_instance();` does this.  Instead of using `$this`, use `$CI`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, this is great idea bro

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using helper and CodeIgniter constructor.

1. You can create custom helper my_helper.php in that write your function

   ```
   function is_logged_in() {
     $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
     if (!isset($user)) { 
      return false; 
     } 
    else { 
      return true;
    }
   }
   ```
2. In controller  if its login.php

   ```
   class Login extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           if(!is_logged_in())  // if you add in constructor no need write each function in above controller. 
           {
            //redirect you login view
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I think using hooks is pretty easy. Just create a hook to check `$this->session->user`. It will be called in every request.

Answer (score 2):

Get all user's data from session.

In the **Controller**,

```
$userData = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

In the **View**,

```
print_r($userData);
```

Answer (score 2):

I coded like this according to above answers.. And this is running for me
Create file my_helper.php

```
<?php 
    function _is_logged_in() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            return true;        
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Edit in autoload.php file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('my');
```

In your Controller file

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if(!_is_logged_in())  
        {
            redirect("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this on your folder core file ci_controller at function __construct() to check all controller ():

```
function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(! $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');)
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```