# How to check user if logged in My_Controller at CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I want to create a new controller which checks all other controller and methods if the user logged in already. I am using session by the way. As stated here [CodeIgniter - How to check session to be used at every methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259617/codeigniter-how-to-check-session-to-be-used-at-every-methods) and [here](http://stevenlu.com/posts/2012/09/01/inheriting-a-base-controller-in-codeigniter/) .

I need to create My_Controller.php inside `application/core` folder.

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

Public_Controller.php

```
<?php
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // do some session stuff here :)
    }
}
```

Admin_Controller.php

```
<?php
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // do some session stuff here :)
    }
}
```

What should I add inside the 2 new controller so I can use it in `controller` like base.php? Or how can I implement the session checking? Sorry, it is very hard for me to explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - How to check session to be used at every methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259617/codeigniter-how-to-check-session-to-be-used-at-every-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make ur My_controller be like this:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session'); // if you are loading session library automatically in the autoload model, then you dont need this line.
        /*---- you can do the session related work in the My_Controller as well if needed-----*/
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_user')== true)
           {
               // session related work;
           }
    }
}
?>
```

then in the public controller make the following changes

```
<?php
include('my_controller.php');
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /*---- if session checking is done in the My_Controller then you might not need to do it here again---*/
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_user')== true)
           {
               // session related work;
           }
    }
}
```

similarly proceed with the other controller