# jQuery After the page is refreshed remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The user after logging in remove hidden class.Mean After the page is refreshed.How can I do ?

**My jQuery code:**

```js
$.ajax({
  type :"POST",
  url  : link,
  dataType: "json",
  data : $("#girisform").serialize(),
  success: function(){
   $("#hosgeldiniz").removeClass("hidden");
   $(".close").trigger("click");
   $("#giris").trigger("click");
   setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://tantunisiparis:8080/"
   }, 1300);   
   $("#userinfo").removeClass("hidden");      
   },
   error: function()
   {
   $("p#hata2").removeClass("hidden");
   $("p#hata2").html("HATA! Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.");
   } 
                });
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
            <nav style="float:right">
              <ul> 
                <li id="girisyap"><a href="#" id="login-btn">GİRİŞ YAP</a></li>
                <li id="kayitol"><a href="#" class="register-btn">KAYIT OL</a></li>
                <li id="userinfo" class="hidden"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi');?></a></li>
              </ul>          
            </nav>
          </div>
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: please create fiddle/plnkr

Comment: Ne yapmak istiyorsun acaba :)

Comment: @VolkanYılmaz abi <li> 'deki hidden olan bölüm varya ora gözükmeyecek eğer giriş başarılıysa o class silinecek. Bunu yapıyorum ama orada sayfayı yenileme kodu var kullanıcının ismi gözükmesi için yukarda yeniletiyorum.Bu seferde remove dediğim class tekrar ekleniyor

Comment: Ajax ile giriş yapmaya çalışıyor doğru ise hide classını kaldırıp sayfayı mı yeniletmeye çalışıyorsun acaba? Doğru mu anladım.

Comment: @VolkanYılmaz evet hepsi çalışıyor hidden class'ı kalkıyor sayfayı yeniliyor.Ama sayfa yenilendiği için tekrar geliyor hidden class'ı.Sayfayı yenilemezsemde kullanıcı adı gelmiyor yukarıya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you change php code. Reflesh page check user logged.

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <nav style="float:right">
        <ul> 
            <?php if ( !is_logged_in() ){ ?>
                <li id="girisyap"><a href="#" id="login-btn">GİRİŞ YAP</a></li>
                <li id="kayitol"><a href="#" class="register-btn">KAYIT OL</a></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li id="userinfo" class="hidden"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi');?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>          
    </nav>
</div>
```

Look at : [How to check user if logged in My_Controller at CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678798/codeigniter-check-for-user-session-in-every-controller)

Comment: Evet bu mantıklı abi şimdi aklıma geldi teşekkürler deneyeceğim!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your script, add after success

```
$("#userinfo").removeClass("hidden");
```

Try this

```
<li id="userinfo" class="<?php if($this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi') == "") {echo "hidden";} ?>"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi');?></a></li>
```

Comment: The page refreshed to try addclass "hidden"

Comment: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi');?> what is use of this line

Comment: <li id="userinfo" class="<?php if($this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi') == "") {echo "hidden";} ?>"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('kullaniciadi');?></a></li> try this. if user is logged in then nothing added in class else echo hidden class

Comment: Wow! Worked. Very big thanx