# How to solve - Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use session in all controllers, but can't get success.

Here is my controller code of library.

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('NO direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();          

    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
        return isset($user);
    }
}

?>
```

And here I am inherit It in my other controller file.

```
class Homepage extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function CheckSession()
    {
        if ($this->is_logged_in())
        {
            echo '111';
        }
    }
}
```

I also try helper but giving me same error.

```
<?php
        function is_logged_in() {
        // Get current CodeIgniter instance
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // We need to use $CI->session instead of $this->session
        $user = $CI->session->userdata('user_data');
        if (!isset($user)) { return false; } else { return true; }
    }
    ?>
```

autoload.php part

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','file','login');`

`$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');`

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session', 'email', 'form_validation', 'MY_Controller');`
I am [Following this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678798/codeigniter-check-for-user-session-in-every-controller).

Comment: have you loaded session library in your autoload file?

Comment: @DharaVihol yes I done it.

Comment: Could you write the error you get, and the autoload.php part concerning this ?

Comment: When I try controller it say's `**
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found**`

Answer (score 1):

either you need to autoload session library in your authoload.php like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

or load session library in constructor of library file like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```